# Ideal line spacing for the very first line

Tags: line-spacing

Question: I am preparing a document with header-footer in which how can i reduce the blank space above the first line of paragraph? infact i dont know whether it is possible or not. please help me.

And one more question what are the ideal measures for line spacing and header-footer for a A4 paper.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{Left top}
\rhead{Right top}
\chead{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{Leftfoot}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\large

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.5} ` is going to make _very_ weird spacing. You are specifying that latex should make the lines of a paragraph be just half their normal distance apart, but not changing the letter size which will be larger than this??????

Comment: Ohhh.. sir what's your suggestion?

Comment: just don't do that:-)

Comment: also why `\hspace{1pt}` to get a space 1pt larger than a normal word space?

Comment: Just for little space

Comment: but a space of 1pt more than a normal word space is a big(ger) space not a little one.

Comment: @snehal, I don't think, that this is really a M (as in minimal) working example.  For example, all the ams-packages could be swept away without any significant changes in the outcome.<BR>I'd argue like David Carlisle, that you shouldn't use `\baselinestretch{}` at all.  Furthermore, I think, the asthetics of the result will be at least adequate, if not more :-)  You should not try to remove the skip between the head line and your text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to decrease the size between the header and your text area, you have to reduce the `\headsep` length, as I did in this MWE.

I removed 1 cm from its actual value.  As you will see, its new length will be way to short, as the text will be printed over the header.  You have to adapt the value to your needs.  Maybe you are looking for something like `\setlength{\headsep}{0.2cm}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{Left top}
\rhead{Right top}
\chead{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{Leftfoot}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

%% This will reduce the skip from the head to the text area.
\addtolength{\headsep}{-1cm}
\begin{document}
%\large

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Have fun (and keep those original LaTeX layout settings---they are beautiful and well chosen)

Jan

Answer (score 1):

Comment the following package: `\usepackage{parskip}`. This will help to reduce the above space of every paragraph.

Comment: My Solution was correct or not

Comment: it was not the correct answer.  If you comment out or remove that package, normal paragraph indent will occur.  That is the only thing, that will change.  The question was, to remove the skip between header and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following command in the preamble part \setlength{\headsep}{0.2cm}

[image]

Comment: it would be better to have edited/corrected your first answer rather than post a second answer.